# WPF RichTextBox RTL

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, right-to-left

I am having troubles with RTL support in RichTextBox and WPF.
When I am trying to write using RTL the following sentence in RichTextBox - "9*11" the number flip sides between the astrik. 
My keyboard is in hebrew mode 
As you can see it is "11*9" and not "9*11", any ideas?

[image: RTL Error Example]

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed anything in the properties of RichTextBox besides: FlowDirection="RightToLeft"?
Can you try with English Keyboard?

Comment: Using the english keyboard it's alright..I changed the Language to be "he-IL".